# Calling a VF page in a lightning component

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, visualforce-component, lightning-apps

I have a VF page which renders a PDF with a custom controller in it for my custom object. For the same, I have written a onclick JS button which is displayed in my classic view.

```
window.open("apex/Letter?Id={!Letter__c.Id}","_blank");
```

Now, I need to display the same 'letter' button in lightning view for which do I need to create only a lightning component or entire lightning package? I have created the lightning app for my object.

Comment: You can check this link and see if that helps: https://medium.com/@ToAnshulVerma/salesforce-lightning-generate-pdf-from-lightning-components-with-in-memory-data-cd5dffe0fe25

Comment: @MandyKool you might want to post a summary of the contents on this link, to maybe get it accepted as an answer by the OP.